# How to add custom field to upload image in registration.phtml file

Tags: magento-1.9, image, image-upload

How to add custom option(field) where when customer create his/her account he/she can upload his her image and also in edit file he/she can resize or manipulate this image

Answer (score 1):

There is ***free extension*** available for that

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/avatar.html

> Note:: I am not promoting this extension just found in search result
>   that's why I am placing here

If you want to ***customize*** then you can try below link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800766/customer-image-upload-and-resize-in-magento